# Xamarin.iOS cannot find type BaseType attribute

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin-studio

I was looking into Objective-C protocols and delegates and was trying to implement a custom one in Xamarin.iOS.  I was following the example in the Xamarin documentation for "Binding Protocols"

```cs
[BaseType (typeof(NSObject))]
[Model][Protocol]
public interface INITableViewCellDelegate {

}
```

for some reason I cannot find the BaseType attribute.  I cannot reference it.  My current list of namespaces for the project are:

```cs
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using MonoTouch.Foundation;
using MonoTouch.UIKit;
using MonoTouch.CoreGraphics;
using MonoTouch.ObjCRuntime;
```

I'm expecting that it should be under System or MonoTouch.ObjCRuntime.  Can anyone shed some light?  I've checked other questions on StackOverflow involving binding protocols and many examples show the same MonoTouch usings.

Thank you

Comment: In more recent builds, there is actually a problem w/XS. See [this bug](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=52553)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Make sure you are using an iOS Binding Project

[image]

Comment: Maybe I should have clarified a bit more.  Is it possible to generate our own C# Protocols.  I'm not trying to bind from a native library.  I know I could use .NET events, but I was interested in using the delegate approach since I am trying to create a couple delegates that I want to fire on the UITableView level.  I guess I'm going through the exercise to see if it is possible.  The more I think about it though it seems like the basetype attribute isn't necessary.

Comment: Ahh I see, yeah the Xamarin.iOS API has Delegates that you can implement like interfaces in C#, this document should help you to get started http://docs.xamarin.com/guides/ios/application_fundamentals/delegates,_protocols,_and_events/

Answer (score 2):

`[BaseType]` attributes are only used in projects of type "iOS Binding Project" and are not available at runtime.

So make sure you're doing an "iOS Binding Project" that'll be processed by the `btouch` tools and will generate bindings for your native library.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem because I just blindly added the files that Sharpie creates to my project without thinking.

When you create a new iOS binding library, it creates two files: `ApiDefinition.cs` and `Structs.cs`. These are empty except for a namespace that matches the project name.

When Sharpie is run it creates two files: `ApiDefinitions.cs` and `StructsAndEnums.cs`. These are the pure definitions and do not exist in a namespace. Do not add these files to your project. Instead;

1. Copy all the contents of `ApiDefinitions.cs` and paste it in the empty namespace in `ApiDefinition.cs`.
2. Copy all the contents of `StructsAndEnums.cs` and paste it into the empty namespace in `Structs.cs`.

Hopefully it should now build.